# Stack and heap and equality testing

Tags: java

In terms of references and their implementation on the heap and the stack how 
equality testing for arrays is different from that for integers?

If your wondering why such different edit, i can post questions new question...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please: (1) undo the edit; (2) post a separate question.

Comment: @aix, i cant post new questions, stack overflow wont allow.

Comment: Does it give you an error message of some sort?

Comment: @aix "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more." I think it is because to many people have downgraded my question.

Comment: I don't think editing an existing question to ask something else entirely is a solution to that.

Answer (score 1):

The complete path would be: /user/web/docs/abc.html

UNIX based just means that the operating system of the server is some kind of a UNIX.

Comment: That assumes the document sits in the root. The question doesn't say if it does or not.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, but without guessing this you can't answer the question.